# How do I lower the resolution scale in DX11?

Tags: directx11, resolution

I've tried a lot of things including lowering the backbuffer size but that causes terrible scaling that I can't really control. I've also tried rendering the scenes to a smaller texture then scaling it up but that requires me to change all my coordinates and I'm pretty sure there's a better way. 
I'm trying to scale 800x600 scenes down to 200x150 then scaling them back up.

Comment: "but that requires me to change all my coordinates" — your coordinates are measured in pixels? Can you show us an example of how you're drawing your content currently and what you'd need to change?

Comment: If this is, as I suspect, for a 2D game, you may not be aware that the dimensions used in your ortho matrix don't have to match your backbuffer size. So you can use an 800x600 ortho matrix with any size backbuffer, and you won't need to change layout coords or dimensions. But I smell an XY problem. How about you tell us what you're trying to do, rather than how you' ré trying to do it?